# how do I include native module (not installed from npm) in my react-native application

Tags: android, react-native, native

I am writing a native module (Android) for a react-native application I am working on. I am not publishing it to npm. This will be used locally in my application. I am trying to understand how I can include the native module, which won't be in node_modules directory, in the javascript code?

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only going to use your module in that one app, you could simply put it in your projects android/app/ directory. Making your native module accessible to JavaScript works exactly the same: extend `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` and `ReactPackage` then create an instance of your package in your `MainActivity`s `getPackages` method.

If you want to re-use your module you could also make it a separate project and put a local path or private git repo in your package.json

Comment: Thanks much, Daniel. I really appreciate your quick response to my question!